# how i can execute this code in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

This operation can only occur on the UI Thread.
can someone tell me how i can solve this issue in silverlight

```
mydll.classishere.givemestring((x) =>
            {
                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(x, UriKind.Relative), "_blank");

            });
```

Comment: What is your issue? That it can only occur on the UI thread? This isn't something you'll be able to "solve", as youre doing a operation involving the UI (a UI window navigation that will cause a repaint). You're not going to be able to do this in the background. The most you could do is create the URI object in the background and pass it to the Window.Navigate, but that's so little overhead as to not even bother.

Comment: can someone show me process then my code wait for the process and then open the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this adjustment to flip the callback execution to the UI Thread:

```
mydll.classishere.givemestring((x) => 
{
     Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
          System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(x, UriKind.Relative), "_blank");  
     }
}
```